# Xpath: locate a node by multiple attributes of a parent node

Tags: xpath

Here is the code:

```
<li class="abc">
    <div class="abc">
         <input type="checkbox">
    </div>

    <div class="xyz">
        <div class="headline">Mongo like candy</div>
    <div>
</li>

<li class="abc">
    <div class="abc">
        <input type="checkbox">
    </div>

    <div class="xyz">
        <div class="headline">Candygram for mongo</div>
    <div>
</li>
```

Xpath challenge. I want locate the checkbox of the li which contains the headline "Mongo like candy" so I can select it using Selenium. In other words, how do you locate the checkbox from here:

```
li//div[@class='abc']//input[@type='checkbox']
```

but qualifying it with a different attribute within the same parent node:

```
li//div[@headline][contains(text(),"Mongo like candy")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to qualify the final path with a predicate, i.e.

```
li[/*predicate here*/]//div[@class='abc']//input[@type='checkbox']
```

The predicate expresses the condition on the li that you want:

```
.//div[@class='headline' and contains(text(), "Mongo like candy")]
```

Putting them together yields:

```
li[.//div[@class='headline' and contains(text(), "Mongo like candy")]]//div[@class='abc']//input[@type='checkbox']
```

Answer (score 1):

something like

> li[div[@class='xyz']//div[@class='headline' and contains(text(),"Mongo like candy"))]]//input[@type='checkbox']

unless I messed up parentheses. (that is, you select not just `li`, but the proper `li`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. This didn't work for me, maybe because it's looking for that input element following the headline element as opposed to being a sibling.

Comment: Funnily enough the @arayq2 answer is the same, except for he skips check for 'xyz' div, doing `.//` instead. So you probably failed to adapt it to your needs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Even this works:

```
//li[1]/div[1]/input[@type='checkbox']
```

It may fail if more div tags are introduced in the page.